# How do I initialise objects in a partial view for use by multiple controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I hope this is something obvious that I've just consistently overlooked and the community can set me on the right path.

I have a news article controller, but I want to be able to use a "common" ticker list on different views. How do I initialise this "@article_list" if I'm using the partial in a few controllers? Apparently it is of the opinion that using a helper is not the solution, since helpers are just for view logic. So where do I put this initialiser that would be available to every controller *as* required? I shouldn't put them in application controller should I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `before_filter` method, i.e. something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def set_article_list
    @article_list = ArticleList.all # or any onther selection
  end
end

class NewsArticleController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_article_list, only: :action1

  def action1
  end
end

class AnotherNewsArticleController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_article_list, only: :another_action1

  def another_action1
  end
end
```

**UPDATE:**

Indeed, there will be problem with a fat ApplicationController. To avoid it it's possible to use module (almost @carolclarinet describe it below):

```
module ArticleList
  def set_article_list
    @article_list = ArticleList.all # or any onther selection
  end
end

class NewsArticleController < ApplicationController
  include ArticleList

  before_filter :set_article_list, only: :action1

  def action1
  end
end

class AnotherNewsArticleController < ApplicationController
  include ArticleList
  before_filter :set_article_list, only: :another_action1

  def another_action1
  end
end
```

And

Comment: From a code design perspective, doesn't this go against all modern "best" practices? "Setting the article list" is not the responsibility of the application's controller. It actually belongs in the domain of the article controller. Is your example just the rails way? Seems like in the end the application controller would end being responsible for a *lot* more than it should -- fat?!?

Answer (score 0):

You can create, essentially, a query object that is only responsible for returning what you need for `@article_list`, for example, building off of Psylone's answer:

```
class ArticleList
  def ticker_articles
    ArticleList.all # or any onther selection
  end
end
```

This class could go in `lib`, `app/models`, `app/query_objects`, `app/models/query_objects`, wherever it makes sense for you. This is a bit outside The Rails Way so there's no convention about where these types of objects should live.

Then in whatever controller you need this, do:

```
@article_list = ArticleList.new.ticker_articles
```

For more explanation of query objects, see [this codeclimate article](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/) #4. Depending on what you're doing to set `@article_list`, this might also be called a service object (#2) or something else entirely. No matter what you call it though, its responsibility would be to return the value you need for `@article_list` and that's it.

Comment: `@article_list = ArticleList.new.ticker_articles` would need to be "copied" to every controller that displays a view that has an "article_list" view, right?

Comment: Correct. You could combine this with the `before_filter` technique that Psylone suggested.